Mapsui doesn't render all the point features from a memory layer
I am creating an application that makes use of Mapsui. One of my goals is to display a series of points with information on the map.
To do this I have followed the samples provided by Mapsui: https://mapsui.com/samples/ (Category: Info, Sample: Single Callout)
After having implemented and tested it and there are many points that are not shown.
I have debugged the application and the layer that stores the points remains unchanged at all times. This behavior is correct, this layer is the final layer to be displayed, but when rendering not all points are rendered.
Here are the codes that are used for this case:
Method for layer creation
private MemoryLayer CreatePointLayer(List<GeoPoint> points)
{
    return new MemoryLayer
    {
        Name = "Incidencias",
        IsMapInfoLayer = true,
        Features = new MemoryProvider(SetFeaturesForPoints(points)).Features,
        Style = SymbolStyles.CreatePinStyle(symbolScale: 0.7),
    };
}

Method for customize features
private IEnumerable<IFeature> SetFeaturesForPoints(List<GeoPoint> points)
{
    if (points != null)
    {
        return points.Select(p =>
        {
            var feature = new PointFeature(SphericalMercator.FromLonLat((double)p.Longitude, (double)p.Latitude).ToMPoint());
            Incidencia incidencia = IncidenciasSingleton.Instance.GetIncidencias().Where(incidencia => incidencia.Identificador == p.IncidenciaIdent).FirstOrDefault();

            feature["Título"] = incidencia.Titulo;
            feature["Fecha del incidente"] = incidencia.FechaIncidente;
            feature["Incidente cerrado"] = incidencia.IncidenteCerrado;
            feature["Última actualización"] = incidencia.UltimaActualizacion;
            feature.Styles.Add(CreateCalloutStyle(feature.ToStringOfKeyValuePairs()));
            feature["Enlace"] = incidencia.Enlace;

            return feature;
        });
    }

    return null;
}

Method for map configurations
public Task<Mapsui.Map> ConfigureMap(ILayer layer)
{
    _mapControl.Map = new Mapsui.Map();
    _mapControl.Map.Layers.Add(OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
    _mapControl.Map.Layers.Add(layer);
    _mapControl.Map.Navigator.RotationLock = true;
    return Task.FromResult(_mapControl.Map);
}

UPDATE: The problem stemmed from the points in question, not from Mapsui.
In fact Mapsui was displaying the points correctly and the points had been repeated.

Perhaps an exception occurs during rendering. To find out you need to turn on logging: https://mapsui.com/documentation/logging.html

Thank you for answering @pauldendulk. I have already found the problem and as I suspected it was not Mapsui. The dots are filtered before displaying them and somehow two dots were being repeated many times, resulting in a lot of features but all the same.
Still, thanks for the help.
